# Rspec/Capybara loading in progress, circular require considered harmful

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, capybara, rspec-rails

Unsure if this is a Capybara issue, but I just did a fresh install of Rails (4.1.1) and Rspec Rails (3.0.1) and I would like to use Capybara (2.3.0), but having never used it I'm running into issues. I created a "spec" in *spec/features* and the spec itself runs and passes as expected, but I get the following "warnings" when rspec is run. Any ideas? Do I just need to disable warnings at the ruby level or something?

```
/Users/typeoneerror/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@doki/gems/mail-2.5.4/lib/mail/network/delivery_methods/sendmail.rb:53: warning: shadowing outer local variable - to
/Users/typeoneerror/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@doki/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247: warning: loading in progress, circular require considered harmful - /Users/typeoneerror/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@doki/gems/capybara-2.3.0/lib/capybara.rb
    from /Users/typeoneerror/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@doki/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in  `<main>'
    from /Users/typeoneerror/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@doki/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in  `eval'
    from /Users/typeoneerror/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@doki/bin/rspec:23:in  `<main>'
    from /Users/typeoneerror/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@doki/bin/rspec:23:in  `load'
    from /Users/typeoneerror/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@doki/gems/rspec-core-3.0.0/exe/rspec:4:in  `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/typeoneerror/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@doki/gems/rspec-core-3.0.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:38:in  `invoke'
    from /Users/typeoneerror/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@doki/gems/rspec-core-3.0.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:70:in  `run'
    from /Users/typeoneerror/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@doki/gems/rspec-core-3.0.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:85:in  `run'
    from /Users/typeoneerror/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@doki/gems/rspec-core-3.0.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:97:in  `setup'
    from /Users/typeoneerror/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@doki/gems/rspec-core-3.0.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1051:in  `load_spec_files'
    from /Users/typeoneerror/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@doki/gems/rspec-core-3.0.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1051:in  `each'
    from /Users/typeoneerror/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@doki/gems/rspec-core-3.0.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1051:in  `block in load_spec_files'
    from /Users/typeoneerror/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@doki/gems/rspec-core-3.0.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1051:in  `load'
    from /Users/typeoneerror/Dev/Doki/engines/doki_core/spec/features/accounts/sign_up_spec.rb:1:in  `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/typeoneerror/Dev/Doki/engines/doki_core/spec/features/accounts/sign_up_spec.rb:1:in  `require'
    from /Users/typeoneerror/Dev/Doki/engines/doki_core/spec/rails_helper.rb:7:in  `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/typeoneerror/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@doki/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in  `require'
    from /Users/typeoneerror/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@doki/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in  `load_dependency'
    from /Users/typeoneerror/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@doki/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in  `block in require'
    from /Users/typeoneerror/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@doki/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in  `require'
    from /Users/typeoneerror/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@doki/gems/rspec-rails-3.0.1/lib/rspec/rails.rb:9:in  `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/typeoneerror/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@doki/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in  `require'
    from /Users/typeoneerror/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@doki/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in  `load_dependency'
    from /Users/typeoneerror/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@doki/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in  `block in require'
    from /Users/typeoneerror/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@doki/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in  `require'
    from /Users/typeoneerror/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@doki/gems/rspec-rails-3.0.1/lib/rspec/rails/vendor/capybara.rb:2:in  `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/typeoneerror/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@doki/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in  `require'
    from /Users/typeoneerror/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@doki/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in  `load_dependency'
    from /Users/typeoneerror/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@doki/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in  `block in require'
    from /Users/typeoneerror/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@doki/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in  `require'
    from /Users/typeoneerror/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@doki/gems/capybara-2.3.0/lib/capybara/rspec.rb:1:in  `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/typeoneerror/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@doki/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in  `require'
    from /Users/typeoneerror/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@doki/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in  `load_dependency'
    from /Users/typeoneerror/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@doki/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in  `block in require'
    from /Users/typeoneerror/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@doki/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in  `require'
    from /Users/typeoneerror/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@doki/gems/capybara-2.3.0/lib/capybara.rb:5:in  `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/typeoneerror/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@doki/gems/capybara-2.3.0/lib/capybara.rb:320:in  `<module:Capybara>'
    from /Users/typeoneerror/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@doki/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in  `require'
    from /Users/typeoneerror/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@doki/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in  `load_dependency'
    from /Users/typeoneerror/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@doki/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in  `block in require'
    from /Users/typeoneerror/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@doki/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in  `require'
    from /Users/typeoneerror/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@doki/gems/capybara-2.3.0/lib/capybara/dsl.rb:1:in  `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/typeoneerror/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@doki/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in  `require'
    from /Users/typeoneerror/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@doki/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in  `load_dependency'
    from /Users/typeoneerror/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@doki/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in  `block in require'
    from /Users/typeoneerror/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@doki/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in  `require'
/Users/typeoneerror/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@doki/gems/capybara-2.3.0/lib/capybara/node/matchers.rb:121: warning: assigned but unused variable - e
/Users/typeoneerror/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@doki/gems/capybara-2.3.0/lib/capybara/selenium/driver.rb:119: warning: assigned but unused variable - a
```

Comment: I had the same issue when I upgraded to RSpec 3 - and Myron's answer is correct, turn off the warnings.

Comment: This also happens with the sass gem (it gets the cirular require warning) from a stock `rails new` (at least for 4.1.1 and 4.1.2) when you add rspec-rails and run the rails generators to install rspec and create a features spec. The fix is the same as described, remove --warnings from your generated .rspec file.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

Remove `--warnings` from `.rspec`.  The generator in rspec 3.0.0 included this setting, but we've realized it was a mistake -- while it's good to encourage users to write warning-free code, it's confusing for users to get these warnings without being sure why.

For more info:

https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/issues/1571

Comment: removing "--warnings" from .rspec will fix the problem but a lot of the warnings themselves seem to be caused by the "--require spec_helper" line in .rspec, at least when you're running rspec under Rails, because the rails_helper.rb generated by "rails generate rspec:install" also explicitly requires spec_helper, resulting in reams of circular dependency warnings.

Comment: @Jeremy - Ruby allows you to require the same file multiple times w/o giving you warnings, so what you describe is unexpected. Can you open an rspec-rails issue for it?

Comment: Thanks!  Put this `config.warnings = false` in the spec_helper and problem solved!